# Spring Boot i18n resolution

Tags: spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I have problems with the resolution of **i18n** in my **spring boot application**. I have this configuration:

**LocaleConfiguration.java** Here I set Locale.US like default language, set the message directory to "src/main/resources/messages" and use locale param to change the language.

```
package com.myproject.web.config;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;

@Configuration
public class LocaleConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Este bean se encargará de resolver que idioma (locale) esta siendo usado
     * actualmente
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }

    /**
     * Este bean se encargara de interceptar el locale que venga a través del
     * parámetro locale de la url
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("locale");
        return lci;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    /**
     * Registramos los filtros
     * 
     * @param registry
     */
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

**My messages files:**

```
/src/main/resources/
----/messages/
-------->messages_es_ES.properties (Spanish message file)
-------->messages.properties (Default messages file. US)
```

Whey I enter in my home, my app shows:

```
??home.welcome_en_US??
```

Looks like can't resolve message files (not even default file!). I should missed something but I can't find. Any help with this?

**Solution**

---

Problem here was the Basename path that I use, I have to define the full path in the classpath without the locale suffix and the file extension (For my use, this):

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

This will search in 
/src/main/resources/ --> classpath
messages/messages --> basename
And then add the required suffix ("es_ES", "en_US"..) 
and the file extension ".properties"

Comment: Please read the documentation on what `baseName` means. It doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Looks like message define the name of the propertie files, not the path :) Thanks to pointing me to the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any similar problem, This was the solution

Problem here was the Basename path that I use, I have to define the full path in the classpath without the locale suffix and the file extension (For my use, this):

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

This will search in

> /src/main/resources/ --> classpath
>
> messages/messages --> basename
>
> And then add the required suffix ("es_ES", "en_US"..)
>
> and the file extension ".properties"

Answer (score 0):

Another way to have it working in a flexible manner is using the properties initialization file: application.properties with the following entry:

```
spring.messages.basename=messages/messages
```

Where the first messages is the name of the folder inside src\resources. Other example, for eventual clarification, is a directory called **bundles** inside src\resources, like this:

```
spring.messages.basename=bundles/messages
```

Using that configuration you don't need the hard coded configuration below in your Springboot main class:

```
...
messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages/messages");
...
```